# Export-CSV not working with my foreach loop

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

I have a piece of code that I wrote which captures some data and write it to a CSV file. I have written it two way. 1) The first way only gives me the last result rather than all the results almost as if it was over writing itself. 2) The second way gives me an error that says "An Empty Pipe Element Is Not Allowed"

WAY 1)

```
foreach ($Computer in $CompObjToRM)
{
Get-ADComputer -Identity $Computer | Select Name, DistinguishedName | Export-CSV C:\T2\ServersToRemoveFromAD2.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

WAY 2)

```
foreach ($Computer in $CompObjToRM)
{
Get-ADComputer -Identity $Computer | Select Name, DistinguishedName
} | Export-CSV C:\T2\ServersToRemoveFromAD2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Way 1 - Yes, your assumption is correct.  Way 2 - `| Out-File` is a command **on its own**.  I get you were trying to pipe the `foreach` into `Out-File` but that's not how those brackets `{ }` work.  The brackets simply indicate the start and end of the `foreach`.  No data will be output, per se, without you telling it how to.

Comment: I think I might be an idiot I think i need to use -NoClobber in the Export-CSV command after piping the command results to my export-csv. Let me fix and run the code and then confirm or deny my stupidity.

Comment: Ok so when I code this: foreach ($Computer in $CompObjToRM)
{
Get-ADComputer -Identity $Computer | Select Name, DistinguishedName | Export-CSV -NoClobber C:\T2\ServersToRemoveFromAD2.csv -NoTypeInformation
}  I get and error: The file 'C:\T2\ServersToRemoveFromAD2.csv' already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the `-Append` switch parameter with `Export-Csv` to avoid it overwriting the same file:

```
foreach ($Computer in $CompObjToRM)
{
    Get-ADComputer -Identity $Computer | Select Name, DistinguishedName | Export-CSV C:\T2\ServersToRemoveFromAD2.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

or use the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet (from which you can pipe all the output to `Export-Csv`)

```
$CompObjToRM |ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADComputer -Identity $_ | Select Name, DistinguishedName 
} | Export-CSV C:\T2\ServersToRemoveFromAD2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

---

The big difference here is that `foreach($thing in $things){}` is a builtin semantic feature of the language, whereas `ForEach-Object` is a *cmdlet* - a piece of reusable code that supports pipeline input and output.

`ForEach-Object` can be a bit slower (and behave slightly differently) than the `foreach` loop, but in most cases, it simply just offers you a greater degree of flexibility in composing your pipeline

Comment: Very nice usage of the `|` before AND after the `foreach` call.  I'd expand on that option, as the original poster was a bit confused why a post pipe didn't work as they expected!  :-)

Comment: @gravity true, updated the answer with a few paragraphs (feel free to add)